# Universal method to get results from Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to do multiple non-linked results to a database so I'm using Task.WhenAll to get data. I have helper method:

```
public static async Task<(T1, T2)> WhenAll<T1, T2>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2)
{
     await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
     var result1 = await task1;
     var result2 = await task2;
     return (result1, result2);
 }
```

Usage:

```
var (profile, roles) = await AsyncUtils.WhenAll(
    _repository.GetUserProfile(userId),
    _repository.GetUserRoles(userId)
);
```

Is it possible to rewrite this method universal for receiving 3, 4, 5 arguments?

Comment: That's what `Task.WhenAll` already does.  It takes an arbitrary number of tasks, and returns the results for all of them.

Comment: You don't need this method in the first place. When `await Task.WhenAll()` returns *all* tasks are already finished. You can get their results with `.Result`. No need to create a new state machine with `await task1`, In fact, using tuple notation would result in a lot less code than what you typed here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to have a variable number of generic type arguments. Intances like [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-16?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=netframework-4.7.2) have separate definitions for up to 8 or so generics.

Supporting arbitrary lengths of generics would be a major change to the language.

I.E.

```
public static async Task<(T1, T2)> WhenAll<T1, T2>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2)
{
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
  return (task1.Result, task2.Result);
}

public static async Task<(T1, T2, T3)> WhenAll<T1, T2, T3>(Task<T1> task1, Task<T2> task2, Task<T3> task3)
{
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
  return (task1.Result, task2.Result, task3.Result);
}

... etc for how ever many generics you want to support
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain why return (await task1, await task2, await task3); works exactly like await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
I thought 
return (await task1, await task2, await task3); 

should be the same as 
await task1; 
await task2; 
await task3;  
May be you can give me some directions where I can check it.

Comment: @AlexeyRyazhskikh Why wouldn't it be the same?  What's the difference between waiting for all three tasks to complete, versus waiting for the first, then the second, then the third, to complete?

Comment: `return (await task1, await task2)` is exactly the same as `var result1 = await task1; var result2 = await task2;` it's just somewhat more concise. The tasks are all already started before they are handed to your method, so they're all running concurrently already, so just awaiting each one is enough. The method will return once the last one is completed.

Comment: Yes but WhenAll will handle propagation of exceptions differently. If both methods throw an exception, WhenAll will give you the aggregate of both. Awaiting them serially, you'd only ever know the first task threw. But if that's not important to you...

Comment: That's true, I didn't think about that. Maybe `await Task.WhenAll(...)` and then just call `return (task1.Result, task2.Result)` to avoid the multiple awaits.

Comment: These functions don't work like `Task.WhenAll()`. `WhenAll()` does *not* wait for tasks in turn, nor does it *throw* in turn, if one of them fails. The way those functions are written if `task2` fails execution will have to wait until `task1` completes before throwing

Comment: Edited answer to add `await Task.WhenAll(...)`